# Moving Bitmap region

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, drawing

In order to make my question more understandable I give you pseudocode snippet:

```
// dx (i.e. offset value) can be arbitrary. 
for(i = 0; i < bitmap.columnsCount - dx; i++)
{
    // "=" means copy pixels from one column to another.
    bitmap.column[i] = bitmap.column[i+dx];
}
```

How should I do this? Of course I can take raw pixels through LockBitmap and then somehow use MarshalCopy or unsafe section... But this is ugly and too complicated. Is there are better way?

I tried to find something similar to `MoveBitmapRegion()` method, but i can't. The idea of ​​drawing bitmap to itself did not work:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, new Rectangle(dx, 0, bmp.Width - dx, bmp.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Making a copy of the bitmap helps, but I think it's too expensive operation:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawImage(new Bitmap(bmp), 0, 0, new Rectangle(dx, 0, bmp.Width - dx, bmp.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: Using LockBits is only as ugly as you make it. It can be done quite succinctly and nicely using only LockBits.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: I'm at work at the moment, I'll see if I can work out an example soon-ish]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just whipped this up really quickly at the end of the day so there may be some mistakes, but in the image I tested it seemed to work fine.

```
private static void CopyBmpRegion(Bitmap image, Rectangle srcRect, Point destLocation)
{
    //do some argument sanitising.
    if (!((srcRect.X >= 0 && srcRect.Y >= 0) && ((srcRect.X + srcRect.Width) <= image.Width) && ((srcRect.Y + srcRect.Height) <= image.Height)))
        throw new ArgumentException("Source rectangle isn't within the image bounds.");

    if ((destLocation.X < 0 || destLocation.X > image.Width) || (destLocation.Y < 0 || destLocation.Y > image.Height))
        throw new ArgumentException("Destination must be within the image.");

    // Lock the bits into memory
    BitmapData bmpData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, image.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, image.PixelFormat);
    int pxlSize = (bmpData.Stride / bmpData.Width); //calculate the pixel width (in bytes) of the current image.
    int src = 0; int dest = 0; //source/destination pixels.

    //account for the fact that not all of the source rectangle may be able to copy into the destination:
    int width = (destLocation.X + srcRect.Width) <= image.Width ? srcRect.Width : (image.Width - (destLocation.X + srcRect.Width)); 
    int height = (destLocation.Y + srcRect.Height) <= image.Height ? srcRect.Height : (image.Height - (destLocation.Y + srcRect.Height));

    //managed buffer to hold the current pixel data.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[pxlSize];

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            //calculate the start of the current source pixel and destination pixel.
            src = ((srcRect.Y + y) * bmpData.Stride) + ((srcRect.X + x) * pxlSize);
            dest = ((destLocation.Y + y) * bmpData.Stride) + ((destLocation.X + x) * pxlSize);

            // Can replace this with unsafe code, but that's up to you.
            Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + src), buffer, 0, pxlSize);
            Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + dest), pxlSize);
        }
    }

    image.UnlockBits(bmpData); //unlock the data.
}
```

Essentially you describe the source rectangle of the area you wish to copy (in pixels, not in bytes) i.e Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100) would describe a block 100x100 pixels wide starting at the top left corner of the image.

Next, you describe the upper left corner of the destination rectangle. As much of the source rectangle will be copied to the destination as possible, but if the image isn't wide/tall enough to accommodate the full rectangle, it will be clipped.

And example of usage would be the following:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\254288b\Downloads\mozodojo-original-image.jpg");
CopyBmpRegion((Bitmap)img, new Rectangle(5, 5, 100, 100), new Point(100, 100));
img.Save(@"C:\Users\254288b\Downloads\mozodojo-new-image.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Which had the following results:

[mozodojo-original-image.jpg](http://pasteshack.net/images/455931001341914968.png)

[mozodojo-new-image.jpg](http://pasteshack.net/images/600481001341915003.png)

See how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I will try your solution. But I must say that I started all this in order to improve some drawing performance. I supposed that move-and-draw-only-new-data operation will be faster than redraw-all-data operation. But now I'm not sure about that. Heh...